# Printing starts well but then it breaks down, Anet A8

Tags: pla, print-quality, ultimaker-cura, anet-a8

I'm printing a cylindrical piece but at any moment it breaks down. I tried it two times, both have break down in different place. I'm using a 1.75 mm PLA filament in my Anet A8. I'm using Cura 2.6.2 to export to a `.gcode` file.

This is the original model:

[image: Original model]

And this is the result:

[image: Printed result]

Here is the [G-code file](https://mega.nz/#!1hkyhLBA!xmt7s38vrb7fEh9SkiSYWfgwLxg4WaYED1h6vzUpghg).

Comment: What temperature are you using? Seems the temp is way to high, so either cool better or lower the print temp (if that's possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thought that pops into my mind is insufficient cooling. Consider to either slow down the nozzle speed or to construct a toss-away model nearby. I prefer the toss-away or duplicate model method. It allows the material printed on the first column to cool more effectively while the material on the second column is being deposited.

If the problem persists, add a third column or slow the print speed about 10 mm / second

Comment: I have the speed in 30mm/second, is it too fast?

Comment: @legomolina You can't solve this problem just by reducing the speed. Keep in mind the nozzle radiates heat, so if it always stays within the same, small, area, that area will never get a chance to cool down. You should really consider printing two copies of this model at once, so the extruder will go back and forth between printing the copies and give the layers some time to cool down.

Comment: Ok, ok. I'll give it a try

Comment: @legomolina The stock A8 fan is useless. Set fan to 100%, and print this (if you can) https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2121279

Comment: @tom, I have never reduced speed, only used the additional column method. Perhaps that qualifier means I should have left out that option. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

The [answer by fred_dot_u](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/printing-starts-well-but-then-it-breaks-down-anet-a8#answer-4976) is fine for small prints with relative low cost or batch producing, where a single part is needed several times. But if you print something big or unique it's not cost effective. Slowing down the complete print is also not very time efficient.

In Cura there an option called **Mininum layer time**, which addresses this problem:

```
Cooling -> Minimum Layer Time / Minimum Speed
```

This means that it will only slow down when the print distance for a particular layer is short. Giving the material some extra time to harden. Other layers will be printed at normal speed. Increased print time will be limited this way.

For your situation I would advise you to increase the part cooling, if possible, in conjunction with configuring the *Minimum Layer Time* option mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Shwans and welcome to Stack Exchange! :-) It is better to reference the answer to which you refer by either the URL, as I have done, or the poster's name. Saying `answer one` will be of no use when/if the voting changes the order.

Comment: A side note: this feature was introduced in CURA 2.4, June 2017.