# Slicer line width vs. extrusion multiplier for layer adhesion?

Tags: slicing, extrusion, nozzle, knowledgebase

My question would like to address what would be **better** for **adhesion** and general quality and possibly strength: either *increase the slicer line width* option or *increase the slicer extrusion multiplier* for layer to layer adhesion?

---

This question has a relation to "[Why is it conventional to set line width > nozzle diameter?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6965/5740)". [This answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6966/5740) on that question addresses a phenomenon called [die swell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_swell) to [explain](https://youtu.be/Cmu4-Y8JKU8?t=32) that the extrusion width is generally larger than the nozzle diameter even if the line width in the slicer is set to the nozzle diameter. Basically, increasing the line width increases the extrusion multiplier, so why not set that directly?

[image: Die swell explained]

Comment: Related: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/why-and-how-am-i-supposed-to-change-the-extrusion-multiplier

Comment: See also: [What's the difference between “Initial Layer Width” and “Initial Layer Flow” in Cura?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/whats-the-difference-between-initial-layer-width-and-initial-layer-flow-in)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Generally speaking*, both settings result in the same<sup>1</sup>: The feed rate of the filament gets adjusted. Either you set a general multiplier, or you demand a wider line which does make it set a higher multiplier hidden in the software.

<sup>1 - if you don't look at any other factor that is!</sup>

#### But...

There is always a but, and this one is big:

While we can work with the extrusion multiplier to get wider lines, wider lines do change another setting: it changes the distance between the lines too. Let me show you:

- If you print 100% at 0.4 mm line width, lines are about<sup>2</sup> 0.4 mm wide at 0.4 mm distance.
- If you print 100% at 0.5 mm line width, lines are about<sup>2</sup> 0.5 mm wide at 0.5 mm distance.
- If you print 121% at 0.4 mm line width, lines are about<sup>2</sup> 0.5 mm wide at 0.4 mm distance.

<sup>2 - ignoring die swell effects</sup>

The result is pretty clear: the theoretical lines do overlap, which will lead to the polymer goop getting squished and pressed around to bulge up. Luckily, that stuff *usually* ends in the infill on the lower layers, but it can result in very messy sides. You pretty much deliberately chose to massively overextrude!

To say it blatantly: line width changes the overall geometry of the slicing to account for the extra material getting extruded, extrusion multiplier does not.

#### What is the extrusion multiplier for THEN?

Well, using the extrusion multiplier can be done for many reasons, but mainly 2 are interesting:

- Troubleshooting. You can just amp it up or down to test your mechanical properties. Like if your gear ratios on the extruder are correct. Or if your print needs a thicker line to get the first layer sticking.
- Dialing in Filaments. In its core, it is meant to allow to change the flow because different polymer blends might have different mechanical and thermal properties.

  - Different filament blends can have different *bite* of the extruder gear - if the teeth dig in deeper, then the effective diameter of the gear gets smaller. This can partially be mitigated by the extruder design using gears designed to prevent shifting the depth of *bite*.
  - For example, the filler and paint could lead to more thermal expansion and die swell, or they could reduce it. This behavior can be tackled directly by adjusting the extrusion multiplier.
  - Those properties are why you should calibrate your settings when getting a new type (color&manufacturer) of filament. While some manufacturers try to keep the properties along their lines similar, some won't.

It might not look too obvious at first, but I once had printed a model from one roll of white PLA that came from China. Then I got my fingers on some other PLA that was transparent from the same warehouse. I tried to print the exact same .gcode with it again and got a hyper fragile object that just could get squished, every time I used it with the same settings as the white PLA. I had to increase both the extrusion multiplier and change the temperature to get the same strength as with the other PLA.