# What does somebody mean in Cura when he demands a "feeding rate of 105%"?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, speed

In a review for a certain filament I read that somebody recommended "[a feeding rate of 105%](https://www.amazon.de/gp/customer-reviews/RVMUN4CW9ZLKX/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B01080YND6)".

What does he mean, and how could I set this in Cura?

When I search for "*feed*" in the print settings properties of Cura, nothing is found, so I suspect he means "*speed*".

When I search for speed, multiple speed settings turn up, not only one.

How could I do what he recommended?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### [Extruder] feed rate [modifier] is used synonymous to extrusion multiplier

The feed rate of the extruder is the rate at which filament is pushed (fed) into the hotend. An overwrite value that modifies that rate from the normal rate is in most slicers called "extrusion multiplier".

It is a *quickfix* to manipulate print behavior, especially addressing under extrusion due to various problems, such as mis-sized filament or to compensate for deformability of it compared to the filament the extruder is calibrated for.

It is however not a permanent fix. See also [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/why-and-how-am-i-supposed-to-change-the-extrusion-multiplier?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6968/slicer-line-width-vs-extrusion-multiplier-for-layer-adhesion?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/isnt-using-the-extrusion-multiplier-like-cheating/8384#8384)

Comment: This is the right answer. On top of this, such advice from a filament reviewer is not likely to be meaningful unless you have the exact same printer as them, since the *reason* they needed to do this could be tied to their printer's extrusion system, material properties of the filament, or some interaction between the two. Only if they said "this filament is routinely undersized vs the nominal 1.75 mm diameter, so you need to adjust the flow to compensate" would it be meaningful to a general audience.

Comment: The answer correctly translates/explains what is meant by the link source, but actually, the feed rate is incorrectly used in the source, feed rate applies to all steppers simultaneously, not on E alone. And as such Feed Rate is not a synonym for Extrusion Multiplier (in general).

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the linked source (in German *"Die Feeding Rate sollte mit 105 % eingestellt werden"*), with *"a feeding rate of 105 %"* is meant the extrusion multiplier (there is no reference in the source to Cura). This is explained in [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/20006). The answer is correct for the translation, but should have warned for the incorrect wording. Technically, *feed rate* is **not** a synonym for *extrusion multiplier*.

The source is wrongly using the term *"feeding rate"*, feeding rate is the rate at which all steppers are scaled, not solely the E (extruder) stepper.

In G-code this is found to be the `F` parameter, e.g. in `G1 F1200 X76.468 Y148.947 E0.0264` the feed rate of 1200 mm/min is applied on all steppers, in this example X, Y and E. Changing the feed rate changes all speeds for all steppers simultaneously. This is found in G-code [`M220`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M220.html).

The extrusion multiplier (or known as *"Flow Percentage"*) only acts on the E stepper motor, this is not reflected in the G-code, but adjusted in the firmware planner. The G-code to adjust the flow percentage is [`M221`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M221.html)