# Inner layers separating specially on the top

Tags: creality-ender-3, creality-ender-5, delamination

I've been facing an issue with my 3d printer for the past couple of months: My inner layers are not sticking together when I print something vertically.

I'm trying to print white PLA at 200ºC with the following Cura settings on an Ender 5 Pro:

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]
[image]

I've tampered with my settings a bit, but still, it doesn't seem to make any difference.
I'm pretty convinced it's a setting issue... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check your temperature sensors. Examine their position and ensure they are in the correct place (no shifting or bending). Lastly, if you have made any changes in the filament brand or model, you may have encountered this issue. Filaments that have been exposed to air or have become stale do not produce reliable prints.

Answer (score 1):

### You did not mention your line width...

From the print effects I do reckon that you are printing your model with a line width of 0.4 mm from a 0.4 mm nozzle. Due to the physical properties of different filaments, this can result in lines that are actually more narrow than demanded, resulting in delamination of walls like shown.

[To work against all those problems, it is usually best to demand the printer to print lines about 10 % wider than the nozzle, e.g. 0.45 mm.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6965/why-is-it-conventional-to-set-line-width-nozzle-diameter/6967#6967)